# Numba 0.35.0 : Use NumPy out parameter

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm doing some tests to better understand how Numba works with NumPy, here I'm trying to see if Numba can handle out parameter.

```
import numpy as np 
from numba import njit , jit
from time import time 

@njit
def mult(a,b, N = 1000000):
    c = np.zeros_like(a)
    for i in range(N):
        np.multiply(a, b, out=c)
    return c

d = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
e = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

t = time()
e = mult(d,e)

print "Time Elapsed :" + str(time() - t)
```

Without using Numba, the code goes well. It's even quicker than using `@jit` decoration : ~1.2s against ~1.6s with my configuration.

Using `@njit` it leads to that error :

```
 LoweringError: unsupported keyword arguments when calling Function(<ufunc 'multiply'>)
```

Though, [Reading the Numba 0.15.1 doc.](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.15.1/arrays.html) , they say out parameter is supported. What can I do against this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just that numba in nopython mode doesn't support keyword-argument. It works if you pass it as positional argument:

```
@njit
def mult(a,b, N = 1000000):
    c = np.zeros_like(a)
    for i in range(N):
        np.multiply(a, b, c)
    return c
```

However using loops that always do the same thing *can* be a problem with numba because sometimes the numba compiler notices that the result doesn't change between loops and it completely optimizes the loop away - essentially resulting in flawed timings. However in this case I don't think this happened, but you need to be careful when using an aggressive compiler like numba and timing it against a "naive" Python approach.